# Is it possible to change the background colour of a special float page?

Tags: floats

When writing a document with lots of floats on them, one can use the parameter [p] to send each table, figure etc. to a special float page:

```
\begin{figure}[p]
```

But is it possible to gain control over the style of this page? E.g. could I change the background colour to, say, light grey?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 1):

You can test for `\if@fcolmade` (`\legacy_if:nTF` requires a current tex system as the command is rather new, but it could be easily replaced with something working also in older systems if needed).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\IfFloatpageT {}
 {
  \legacy_if:nTF { @fcolmade }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\AddToShipoutPictureBG
 {%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{\IfFloatpageT{\textcolor{gray!20!white}{\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}}}%
 }

\begin{document}

\section{One}
\begin{figure}[p]
\rule{1cm}{0.8\textheight}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}[p]
\rule{1cm}{0.8\textheight}
\end{figure}

\lipsum


\begin{figure}
\rule{1cm}{0.2\textheight}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\rule{1cm}{0.2\textheight}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\rule{1cm}{0.2\textheight}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\rule{1cm}{0.2\textheight}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\rule{1cm}{0.2\textheight}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\rule{1cm}{0.2\textheight}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide any `MWE`, I assumed that you are using standard template, you can try with the following tags:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\begin{document}

\pagecolor{black!10}

\begin{figure}[p!]
\centerline{\includegraphics{example-image.pdf}}
\caption{Caption text}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[p!]
\centerline{\includegraphics{example-image.pdf}}
\caption{Caption text}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[p!]
\centerline{\includegraphics{example-image.pdf}}
\caption{Caption text}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[p!]
\centerline{\includegraphics{example-image.pdf}}
\caption{Caption text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Please revert if it not meets your requirement...