# Changing the page color for a float page

Tags: floats, color, pagecolor

I'm looking for a way to change the page color of a float page. I'm using the `[p]` placement for the respective figure. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pagecolor}

\begin{document}
Text on a clean page. %The page is white by default.
\clearpage
Text before figure. %This page is red already.
\begin{figure}[p]
    \pagecolor{red}\afterpage{\pagecolor{none}}
    Figure text.
\end{figure}
Text after figure.
\clearpage %The float is placed, \afterpage kicks in and restores the page background
Again, text on a clean page.
\end{document}
```

The `\pagecolor` command is carried out as soon as the float is reached in the source, so all the pages up to the float are already red. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500869/is-it-possible-to-change-the-background-colour-of-a-special-float-page) kind of deals with the same problem, however its solution hooks to any float page shipped out. I only want the colored background for certain float pages, not all of them. How can I change the page color for only a certain float page?

(Given the referenced question and solution, I was thinking of adding a conditional that must be set for `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` to change the background, which I could set when I want a colored float page. But it seems inelegant and just too hacky...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the floatpag package, I figured you could use the same trick for pagecolor.  I had to create my on `\thispagecolor` command.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{floatpag}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@thispagecolor}{none}
\let\@pagecolornone=\@thispagecolor
\newcommand{\thispagecolor}[1]{\gdef\@thispagecolor{#1}}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\ifx\@thispagecolor\@pagecolornone\relax
  %\put(1in,-1in) {color=none}%
\else
  \put(0pt,-\paperheight) {\textcolor{\@thispagecolor}{\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}}%
  \global\let\@thispagecolor=\@pagecolornone
\fi}
  
\newcommand{\floatpagecolor}[1]{\gdef\at@float@page{\thispagecolor{#1}}}
\makeatother

\floatpagecolor{red}

\begin{document}
Text on a clean page. %The page is white by default.
\clearpage
Text before figure. %This page is red already.
\begin{figure}[p]
    Figure text.
\end{figure}
Text after figure.
\clearpage %The float is placed, \afterpage kicks in and restores the page background
Again, text on a clean page.
\end{document}
```