# How To Add a border around all pages which is a picture?

Tags: border

I have a picture that is a rectangle and has an open center. I want this image to be my page border. How would I go about doing this?

If I try to make the picture fit the entire page then I can't have the text on the same page that the image is on.

Comment: Like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/801/47927 or this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31135/47927 ?

Comment: exactly like the second one! Although it seems my image is far too complicated to code in LateX using TikZ. Is there a way to do it with an image? For example some word processing softwares allow for the image to go over the text.

Comment: You can use a full page float.  If you already have figures and tables, you can create a new float type (newfloat or float packages).  The floatpag package will even allow you to automatically add the "frame", though it may take some hacking (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/678532/changing-the-page-color-for-a-float-page/678550?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C37.8193#678550).

Comment: So, what you want is to place an image to the background of a specific page? In this case you could also make use of `\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{ ... }`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/629027/47927 . A simple border could directly be drawn using Ti*k*Z, but you can also place an image inside a Ti*kZ* node: `\node {\includegraphics{ ... }};`. If you need more help, consider posting some code ...